# Is there anything better than NFS for sharing directories between linux guests on VMWare?

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs

What are relevant the trade offs for file sharing options between a group of virtualised linux machines running on the same VMWare box?
E.g. high throughput, low latency etc.

I have mainly used NFS. VMWare used hgfs by default. How do they compare?
Are there any other options worth considering (e.g. sshfs).

### Background

We have an application that on physical machines distributes work to slaves via a NFS mounted directory shared on the master.
This configuration is easy to replicate on VMWare. And seems to give adequate performance. However, I was wondering if there is a better way of sharing the directory between linux guests running under VMWare?
I gather shared folders on VMWare use hgfs. Would this be better? Is this the best option?
By better here. I mean likely to give the best performance on the current hardware, which is a single VMWare host.

If so how do I enable it? Despite having installed VMWare tools there doesn't seem to be an option to enable sharing. In VM settings/ properties / options - VMWare tools is listed as shutdown. The entry for shared folders shown on various sites I've googled doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Go with NFS! It will be more portable, if you drop Vmware or scale to several physical servers.